# Is Apple doc for archiving an iPhone app incorrect re "Skip Install build setting"

Tags: xcode, xcode4, archiving

When following the apple doco [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/Xcode4UserGuide/DistApps/DistApps.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010215-CH11-SW1) for archiving an application, i.e. setting  "Skip Install build setting" to YES, when I do then go Product->Archive it does not show up in Organizer/Archives.

However if I ignore the doco and leave "Skip Install build setting" as NO, then I do get a resultant archive appearing in Organizer.

Question - What setting should I be using to make sure the archive is good for distribution?  If the answer is by setting (ie. "Skip Install build setting" ) it to YES, then how do I get around the fact the archive in this case doesn't appear in Organizer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set the `SKIP_INSTALL` build setting for all targets in a scheme but your application, i. e. for all dependencies like frameworks and libraries. Don’t set it for the application target itself.

Comment: can I ask, if you had a project with multiple dependencies, where in XCode4 exactly would you see this setting such that you could see: one of the dependencies set, and the application one not set?

Comment: You do this exactly the same way as you change any other build setting, i. e. select the project (application or dependency) in the files navigator, then select the project or individual targets in the editor and find the respective build setting. Does that make sense?

Comment: ok - so it won't be in your apps target then, it'll be in another target (or event target within a different project) then - this makes sense in terms of where the setting would be - so I'm assuming you can reference another target or project with your application then (just haven't done this before)

Comment: Yes, you can have as many projects in a workspace as you like. (If you don't create a workspace explicitly, one will be created for you when you open a project in Xcode 4.) And of course, you can have as many targets as you like in a project. Say, you develop an app for distribution on the App Store and via your website, and this app uses a shared framework. You'd have two targets in your app project (one for each distribution channel) and you'd add the framework project to the workspace.